# How to make mouse transparent stage in JavaFX 8?

Tags: javafx, window, mouseevent

I know how to make mouse transparent `Node`. But I want to make transparent window in color and mouse events, so that cursor could pass through this window and click on the app which below it.

Here is a minimal code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class MouseTransparentWindow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(192,192,192,0.2);" +
                "-fx-border-width: 1px;-fx-border-color: #1d1d1d");
        stackPane.setMouseTransparent(true);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 400, 250, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.setFill(null);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

It seems it works on Windows, but I need that my code work on all Operating Systems.

Comment: Your code works for me on Windows 10. I've come across a few questions saying this won't work on Macs, but I'm not sure if that's a JavaFX issue or an OS issue.

Comment: @Slaw Oh, I am using MacOS.

Comment: Did you try setting the fill for scene as null? `scene.setFill(null);`

Comment: @trilogy Now I tried, but it is not working anyway.

Comment: Just curious, what are you trying to do with the window behind it?  I can replicate the issue on Mac, where I can see through the scene/stage but cannot actually select the window below, but I'm curious what you're trying to do with that?  There might be a way around to do what you're wanting.

Comment: @kendavidson I am trying to create Timer for controlling my time, so that I can see it all the time by not interfering mouse listeners while I am coding.

Comment: Ah, sadly from googling around there are number of SO questions and JavaFX jira tasks stating that this is a bug on mac 10+ but it looks like none of them have been actioned/resolved.  May need to look at alternatives like smaller window footprint or pushing your app to the system bar.  Definitely something to continue to look into.

Comment: @kendavidson Can JNA solve this problem?

Comment: I would say probably, I've dabbled with Windows COM objects, but implementing a native UI library within JavaFX is a little out of my realm at this point in time.  With that said, as long as you found the native library that allowed you to create windows in the way you wanted, I'm sure it's possible.